# Javascript doesn't work on Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, manifest

My HTML has 2 buttons and a text input. They change the value of the input (-1 and +1).

It just works fine on the code snippet here, but doesn't work on Chrome Extension.

My HTML file calls the JavaScript file, and it is on the manifest too:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="melionline.js"></script>
```

Manifest:

```html
{
 "manifest_version":2,
 "name": "Online Console",
 "version":"1.0",
  
 "description": "Simulador de consola de Online",
 "browser_action":{
 "default_icon": "icon24.png",
 "default_popup": "PrincipalOnline.html"
 },
 "permissions":[
 "activeTab"
 ], 
 
"content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "melionline.js" ]}]
 }
```

```js
document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", changeValue)
var cant=1;
function changeValue() {
    if (cant < 5) {
        cant += 0.5;
    }
    else { cant = 5; }

    var valor = document.getElementById("counter");
    valor.value = cant.toString();


}

document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", changeValue2)

function changeValue2() {
    if (cant >1) {
        cant -= 1;
    }
    else { cant = 1; }

    var valor = document.getElementById("counter");
    valor.value = cant.toString();


}
```

```html
<button id="minus" style="width:6px; text-align:center;" type="button" class="btn btn-default">-</button>
<input style="text-align:center; width:30px; height:30px;" type="text" id="counter" value="1">
<button style="text-align:center; width:6px;" type="button" id="plus" class="btn btn-default" onclick= "changeValue()" >+</button>
```

Comment: Possibly a dumb question, but are you in developer mode?  Unregistered extensions wont work in if you are not in developer mode.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Yes! I am, yesterday I made an extension and it worked fine. Today I have this problem (maybe is a dumb error but I don't realize). Thanks for the tip anyway!

Comment: Please show manifest.json in question

Comment: @JaromandaX done!

Comment: Sounds like you're confusing content scripts and popup (browser_action) scripts - they run in two different pages so it makes no sense to use the same script. To debug the popup, right-click it, then click "Inspect". See also [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Comment: did you try to disable an reinstall extension? ive had some problems because of caching old js file